# All but $35$ values can be payed with coins of $a$ and $b$, and $58$ can't be paid. Find $a$ and $b$.

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

let $a<b$ be positive integers, using coins of values $a$ and $b$ exactly $35$ values cannot be paid exactly without change. $58$ is among these values. Find $a$ and $b$. I managed to solve this, but it took me almost twenty minutes, is there a fast solution for this, also is my solution good? Thanks and regards.

My solution:

> Clearly $(a,b)=1$. Notice every integer $v$ can be canonically written uniquely as $sa+tb$ with $s\in\{0,1\dots b-1\}$ and $t\in \mathbb Z$. A value $v$ can't be formed if and only if $t<0$ in this expression. If a positive integer has canonical expression with $b$ negative then $s\in\{1,\dots b-1\}$ and $t\in\{-1,-2\dots,-a+1\}$. Of all of these expressions half of them are negative because if $x$ is expressed that way so is $-x$. Therefore $(a-1)(b-1)=70\implies (a,b)=(2,71),(3,36),(6,15)$ or $(8,11)$. The first doesn't work as $58=29\times 2$, the next $2$ don't work as they aren't coprime. The last one works as $58=10\times 8 - 2\times 11$. So $a=8,b=11$.

Comment: I can't think of  a faster answer than this.

Comment: Well you can always find $gcd (a,b) = an + bm $.  So gcd (a,b) isn't1.  And you can only do multiples of gcd (a,b).  So the combinations you can't do are precisely the numbers that aren't multiple of gcd.  I don't know what you mean exactly 35 non solutions there are either none or infinite.

Comment: Oh wait.  That there aren't infinite non doable gcd(a,b)=1 and the ones you can't do are the ones that are require negatives to solve.

Comment: @fleablood exactly.

Comment: If $(a,b)=d$ for example, no non-multiple of $d$ can be paid without change. From the proposition, it follows that $(a,b)=1$.

Comment: Find the smallest nb +1 =ka.  Then nb+a and higher can be made change for.  You can make change b,2b,...nb, and a,2a,... (k-1)a and the combos.  Figuring out the formula for the number of combos should be possible.

Comment: Need to find $gcd (a,b)=1;58 <na=mb-1;na-\sum\lfloor (na-i*b)/a\rfloor =35$.  However I have no idea how to solve those.

Comment: Okay, yeah, I can't see any other way to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is good, and it doesn't get much faster.

More generally, the relevant structural result is the following nice symmetry:

1. Let $a, b \ge 0$ be coprime. Then for all $x \in \mathbb{Z}$, $x$ can be formed iff $(ab-a-b) - x$ can't be formed.

Then the following (which are more well-known) are immediate corollaries:

2. The largest integer that can't be formed is $ab - a - b$.
3. There are exactly $\frac{ab-a-b+1}{2}$ nonnegative integers that can't be formed.

To solve the question, by (3) $(a-1)(b-1) = 70$, and $ab-a-b = 69$. Then by (1), since $58$ can't be formed, $69 - 58 = 11$ can be formed.
So we are looking for $a,b$ such that $(a-1)(b-1) = 70$ and $11$ is a sum of $a$s and $b$s. $a = 8$, $b = 11$ quickly follows.

---

**Final remark:** Unfortunately, I do not think there is any nice structure analogous to (1) when there are 3 or more variables.